# How to fix modal window if press ok

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

i have created a modal which has two button functions namely "OK" & "Cancel" onclick of cancel modal will get close but if i try to close by clicking its not closing.

I have trid with  $uibModalInstance.dismiss() for closing modal window by clicking ok

```
$scope.deleteSample = (x) => {
    $http.delete(`/api/sample/${x.sysPk}`)
        .then(resp => {
            loadSamples()
        }, error => {
            console.error('Error in updating', error)
            alert("unable to update")
        })
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss()
}
```

i expecting to get onclick on of ok button modal should close

Comment: Use the `ng-click` directive instead of `onclick`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the promise returned by $uibModal.open(). You can store it in  $scope like below:

```
$scope.instance = $uibModal.open({ 
templateUrl: 'template.html',
  controller: 'modalCtrl',
  controllerAs: '$ctrl'
  .......
})
```

and then use you can close popup with close() function:

```
$scope.instance.close();
```

instead of $uibModalInstance.close.